# What is Spark Peak Execution Memory OffHeap?

Tags: apache-spark, user-interface, memory, off-heap

Spark Version: 3.3
I don't set spark.memory.offHeap.enabled. From official document, it means spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=false(default). But in Spark-History UI, i found that "Spark Peak Execution Memory" is not zero.
Here offheap means executor overhead cost?
Why i could see "offheap" was used here.

Answer (score 0):

You could search `spark.memory.offHeap.enabled` in  Spark-History-UI -> Enviroment to see if it is really `false`. You will get a result if it is `true` else your search matches nothing.

Or adding `--conf spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=` to `true` or `false`